# Create MS Excel Sheet

Tags: silverlight, excel, moonlight

How can I create an MS Excel sheet and download it from a Moonlight/Silverlight app? Regards Lennie

Basically I want to run a report in the Siverlight client and allow the user to download the MS Excel report.

Comment: A little more detail would be helpfull here... Are you trying to create the excel sheet from a server, or a computer that has excell installed? For the download, I would suggest you use a wcf service that reads the excel file as a byte array, and send that through to the silverlight client requesting it.

Comment: More info: "Basically I want to run a report in the Siverlight client and allow the user to download the MS Excel report."

Comment: I assume that the actual report will come from a webservice, so I think the easiest solution would be to pass the url where the report can be downloaded to your html page javascript, and open it from there with window.open()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this previously, its pretty time consuming but you can write it to a XML file on the client side.

A good place to start is to create a new excel sheet save it as an XML file and then you can work out which bits need to change and then work out a way to write the correct information to the XML file.

Although as I said it will take a fair bit of time!!

Edit-

Just found this for you to take a look at-
http://www.rshelby.com/post/creating-excel-worksheet-from-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use [npoi](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)  to generate the excel in server temporarily , until it is downloaded by the user , then delete it .